# What is the usage of rundeck, spinnaker and jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rundeck, spinnaker

Could anyone help me the relationship between rundeck, spinnaker and jenkins?
I have seen jenkins for build and spinnaker for pipeline. And how this run deck is integrated and the usage of them.

I got some info from the below image how spinnaker and jenkins are related. But Run deck also integrated.

[image]

Ref: https://www.opsmx.com/what-is-spinnaker/

Comment: Surprised people replied here as it's more appropriate Q for [DevOps S/E](https://devops.stackexchange.com); usually these get quickly closed/downvoted.

Comment: No boday can be perfect everywhere. I had doubt over this, So I asked. And this platform is for discussion only. More over I have not created any duplicate questions to get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rundeck is focused on automation and operations, Jenkins on CI/CD, you can design workflows integrating Jenkins pipelines on automated Rundeck jobs, take a look at [this](https://www.rundeck.com/jenkins).

Spinnaker: a multi-cloud continuous delivery platform for releasing software changes.

Rundeck: Enable anyone to safely execute self-service operations tasks. Spinnaker looks closer to Jenkins. With Rundeck you can automate everything, not only CI/CD pipelines.

In fact, you can integrate Rundeck with any other solution to deliver automated tasks and save time avoiding interruptions. [This](https://www.rundeck.com/service-requests) is a good example of that.

Comment: Are Rundeck and spinnaker doing the same work?

Comment: Nope, Spinnaker: a multi-cloud continuous delivery platform for releasing software changes, Rundeck: Enable anyone to safely execute self-service operations tasks. Spinnaker looks closer to Jenkins. With Rundeck you can automate everything, not only CI/CD pipelines.

Comment: @MegaDrive68k, would better to edit/add to your answer so it reads as a complete response.